# CSV to CoreData

Tags: database, core-data, csv

I have a database in CSV and want to export it to an app for iPhone with CoreData. Is there a way to parse the fields of the CSV to the entities and atributes of a CoreData model?

My goal is to create a filter in a table view with the name of the atributes (and the user will check yes or no since the atributes are boolean), and to give an entry with the result of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script (python?) to read the file and insert records into a SQLite database--you would then tell core data to use that file when you include it in your project